# Maximal size of set cover

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

Let $S$ be a set of size $1983$, and let $A_1,..,A_k$ be a familiy of subsets of $S$ such that:

- The union of every 3 sets of the family is S.
- For every pair of sets the union of them contains no more than $1979$ elements of $S$.

What is the maximal size of $k$?

I'm pretty stuck here, can someone give me a hint on how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $B_i$ be the complement of $A_i$. Now each pair $B_i, B_j$ have intersection $C_{ij}$ with at least $4$ elements, and $C_{ij} \cap C_{kl}=\emptyset$ for $\{i, j\} \not =\{k, l\}$.

Comment: So I can look of it like that,
I'll insert the sets to my family one by one, The i'th set is adding to my number of total elements at least 4*(i-1) sets (since it has intersection with at least 4 elements with every set and there are no elements that are in 3 different sets).
Therefore, Im looking for the largest $k$ s.t $0+4+8+..+4(k-1) \leq 1983$.

Is this correct?

Comment: @Snufsan Yes. Of course, you must exhibit a construction to show the maximal $k$ is achievable.